# Can I change rokSprocket Images Based On The Viewport Size?

Tags: joomla, joomla-extensions

**Is There A Way To Make rokSprocket Images More Mobile Friendly?**

I have a responsive site, and the mobile viewers are getting bogged down due to my rokSprocket "hero image" slideshow. I don't see ways to change images based on media queries, and I don't see any server side image resizing options.

1. Is there an option that I'm overlooking?
2. Is there any way to turn them into background images so I can alter them in media queries?
3. Is there a way to ignore / add modules based on media queries?

   - *found [this guy](https://www.nonumber.nl/extensions/advancedmodulemanager#changelog) for adding and removing modules. 1st question is still my preferred solution though*

Any direction, documentation, or help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone looking for an answer to this, I ended up making a transparent image with the same aspect ratio as my slides, and I put this image in place of all my rokSprocket images. *(This is to achieve the desired height and width)*

Then I targeted the slides in my CSS

`.sprocket-features-index-1 img {}`

and placed the actual images as background-images.

`.sprocket-features-index-1 img {background-image: url('/images/homeSlide1.jpg');}`

Then I just set the smaller images as media queries

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .home .sprocket-features-index-1 img {background-image: url('/images/homeSlide1-tablet.jpg');}
    .home .sprocket-features-index-2 img {background-image: url('/images/homeSlide2-tablet.jpg');}
    .home .sprocket-features-index-3 img {background-image: url('/images/homeSlide3-tablet.jpg');}
}

@media (max-width: 480px) and (-webkit-max-device-pixel-ratio: 1) {
    .home .sprocket-features-index-1 img {background-image: url('/images/homeSlide1-phone.jpg');}
    .home .sprocket-features-index-2 img {background-image: url('/images/homeSlide2-phone.jpg');}
    .home .sprocket-features-index-3 img {background-image: url('/images/homeSlide3-phone.jpg');}
}

@media (max-width: 480px) and (-webkit-max-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
    .home .sprocket-features-index-1 img {background-image: url('/images/homeSlide1-phonex2.jpg');}
    .home .sprocket-features-index-2 img {background-image: url('/images/homeSlide2-phonex2.jpg');}
    .home .sprocket-features-index-3 img {background-image: url('/images/homeSlide3-phonex2.jpg');}
}
```